# how to use wildcard certificate with ikev2 on strongswan

Tags: ssl-certificate, strongswan, ikev2

I am using a wildcard certificate.

I have managed to setup ikev2 protocol, applied my own certificate but it won't work for subdomains.

Is there any workaround for this or the wildcard should be of a certain format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps in 2017, Strongswan did not support wildcard certificates, but they definitely work today in 2021.  For anyone else running into this question, the solution is to change the configuration of "leftid" in the /etc/ipsec.conf configuration file.  The relevant fields are:

```
conn ikev2-vpn
    left=%any
    leftid=@*.example.com
    leftcert=star_example_com.crt
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
```

Note that the "leftid" configuration setting must use the wildcard name, as it appears in the wildcard certificate.

Comment: Nope, with Strongswan mobile client isn't working. Tried on two servers with the very same config, one with regular LE certificate is working and two with RapidSSL wildcard isn't. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Generally, strongSwan doesn't support wildcard certificates (see e.g. [#794](https://wiki.strongswan.org/issues/794)). For instance, if the server certificate contains `*.example.com` as *subjectAltName* extension strongSwan won't  match `vpn.example.com` against that.

If you have multiple subdomains add a subjectAltName extension for each to the server certificate.

Comment: works with iOS..in the config i use @*.domain.com

Comment: What config are you referring to?

Comment: config for straongswan in /etc/ipsec.conf